# Find value of $ \frac{C_0}{2}-\frac{C_1}{3}+\frac{C_2}{4}+...+(-1)^n\frac{C_n}{n+2}, $ where $C_i = \binom{n}{i} $

Tags: integration, combinatorics, combinations

I saw some posts in the net with solution to this, with lots of calculations on formula for combinations, wondering if it can be obtained with less calculations.

My try:

$ (1-x)^n = C_0-C_1x+C_2x^2 + ... $

$x(1-x)^n = C_0x-C_1x^2+C_2x^3 + ... $

Now integrating both sides and putting x =1, the right hand side becomes the desired expression, but I am stuck on how to calculate left hand side to get the value.

Comment: Substitute $x=1-(1-x)$ then integrate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LHS=
$$\int_{0}^{1}{x(1-x)^ndx} $$
$$=\int_{0}^{1}{(1-(1-x))(1-x)^ndx} $$
$$=\int_{0}^{1}{(1-x)^ndx} - \int_{0}^{1}{(1-x)^{n+1}dx}$$

You can do rest, i believe.

Answer (score 1):

*Another way to do it.*

Consider
$$S=\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i \frac{  \binom{n}{i}}{i+2}x^{i+2}$$
$$S'=\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i \binom{n}{i}x^{i+1}=x\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i \binom{n}{i}x^{i}=x(1-x)^n$$ and then, what @Harshit Raj showed in his/her answer.

When done, just make $x=1$ for the final result.